# Initializing an array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to initialize an array with this code, but it's not displaying the output, i.e

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main() {
   int array[SIZE] = {0}, i = 1;
  
   while( i <= SIZE ) {
      array[i] = 2 * i - 1;
 
      i++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `array[10] = 19;` is invalid: `array[10]` does not exist. The ten elements are `array[0]`, `array[1]`, ..., `array[9]`

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) array[i] = 2 * i + 1;`

Comment: Also... `int array[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}; int size = sizeof array / sizeof *array;`

Comment: why would it display any output? You didn't tell it to display output

Answer (score 2):

The immediate error is in the condition

```
 i <= SIZE
```

note, that since arrays are *zero based*, array of length `SIZE` has items with

```
 0, 1, 2, ..., SIZE - 1
```

indexes. So you can just put

```
 while (i < SIZE)
```

and get (you start assigning from `array[1]`, not from `array[0]`)

```
 trash, 1, 3, 5, ..., 17
```

However, I suggest redesign, why should we not use a typical `for` loop initialization?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
   array[i] = 2 * i + 1;
```

note, `2 * i + 1` - we put `+` since arrays are *zero based*, and we want the first `array` item - `array[0]` - be `1`. This code provides

```
 1, 3, 5, ..., 19
```

values

**Edit:** As *Vlad from Moscow* pointed out in the comments, you can change *index* instead of *condition*:

```
while (i <= SIZE) {
   array[i - 1] = 2 * i - 1;
   i++;
}
```

here we loop over `1, 2, ..., SIZE` but assign vaue to `array[0], array[1], ..., array[SIZE - 1]` items

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko  This  i <= SIZE is not an error. It is a valid condition. The reason of the error is using an incorrect index array[i] = 2*i-1; instead of array[i-1] = 2*i-1;

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: Thank you! I've totally overlooked this posiibility (changing index instead of condition)

Answer (score -3):

You just defined the array, you didn't print it anywhere. Try adding this before your `return 0` statement.

```
for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
    printf("%d\n", array[j]);
}
```

Comment: This will display the array but leaves the code in a state where it can generate a Segmentation Fault at any time. Please mention that in our answer as well.

Comment: This “random life problem” is rather something that would prevent the OP from getting the desired behavior. We are here to help people solve their programming queries. Posting an answer is an option, not a requirement. We want, however to keep the highest standards on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Victor Those that claim SO questions are good only for search engine results would disagree with you. The solution to "I initialized array, nothing is displayed" is "add a `printf` statement", not "add a `printf` statement and yeah since unfortunately your loop has a `<=` instead of a `<`, you'll get a segfault."